# Angular2 Web Workers and importScripts

Tags: import, angular, web-worker

I've been trying to code an Angular2 component with web workers, but I'm having trouble importing code for the worker thread. Here's the start of my component's code:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/web_worker/worker';
import {platform} from "angular2/core";
import {WORKER_APP_PLATFORM, WORKER_APP_APPLICATION} from 'angular2/platform/worker_app';
```

In loader.js, I call importScripts in the following way:

```
importScripts( "https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js",
              "https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/web_worker/worker.dev.js",
              "https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js",
              "../../../../node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js");
```

I've verified that loader.js executes, but when I run the application, I get errors stating that "angular2/web_worker/worker", "angular2/core", and "angular2/platform/worker_app" can't be found. Do I need to import different dependencies in loader.js?